# window.onerror overriden by 3rd party library - how to track that to reinstall my handler back?

Tags: javascript

On our website we want to track all JS error with stacktracejs library. It's very straightforward to install, and we do this in `<head>`:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, file, line, col, error) {
    // callback is called with an Array[StackFrame]
    StackTrace.fromError(error).then(callback).catch(errback);
};
```

then we include Hubspot tracking code in the footer as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async defer src="//js.hs-scripts.com/hs.js"></script>
```

note `async` and `defer` - and at some, unknown point of time, Hubspot's script takes over (reassigns to their function) `window.onerror` - without taking MY function into consideration. That's a bug, from what I understand, and it's reported on their website: https://integrate.hubspot.com/t/tracking-code-overrides-window-onerror/1755

My question is - is that possible to track somehow that function definition was overridden? I understand I can do `settimeout()` but I think that's a poor's man solution. I'm looking for "natural" way if you wish - subscribe to notification or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want that no one replaces your function, you can use `addEventListener` instead.

```
window.addEventListener('error', sendError)
```

Comment: Yes, window.onerror from the other third party will work too. But I think they could use addEventListener as well to not have that problems anymore

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to download the script with something like jQuery $.getScript, this would let you have a callback once the script is fully downloaded and included in DOM.

```
$.getScript( "//js.hs-scripts.com/hs.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    alert("Success!");
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    alert("Fail");
});
```